# Notification for Mouse clicked events in cocoa

Tags: macos, cocoa, mouseevent

I am new to Mac App development, I want Mouse clicked notifications, i.e when we click on mouse a notification must be triggered. Just like keyboard notifications in iOS. What is the notification name we have to use like **UITextViewTextDidBeginEditingNotification** for keyboard in iOS.

Regards

Comment: Mousedown event on NSWindow or NSTextField  or NSCell ?

Comment: Take a  look at https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/HandlingMouseEvents/HandlingMouseEvents.html

Comment: Are you talking about a global mouse event or an event in a particular "window/view"?

Answer (score 0):

Set your NSTextField's delegate to NSTextFieldDelegate,then the method below would be called:

```
- (void)textDidBeginEditing:(NSNotification *)notification;
```

Or call this method `-(void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent{}` if you want to track mouse event